# Selection does not contain a main type. Eclipse error

Tags: java, android

I've made an AVD (android virtual device).
But when i try to run my application, this shows up:

Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.

The error log shows the following:
NUMBER 1: res\drawable-mdpi\testbackg.png:0: error: Resource entry testbackg is already defined.
NUMBER 2: res\drawable-mdpi\testbackg.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
NUMBER 3: C:\Users\Svein Inge\Android Eclipse\Test 1\res\layout\main.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/testbackg.png').

Here's my code (main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/testbackg.png"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/open" />


</LinearLayout>
```

help

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/419415/vc/eclipse-active-editor-does-not and http://www.coderanch.com/t/431735/vc/eclipse-editor-does-not-contain

Comment: This question has a misleading title.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to run your app?  Are you following the instructions found here?

[Building and Running from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-eclipse.html)

Comment: That lesson doesn't tell you how to run an android app.  It sounds like you're trying to run your app as a java app.  Instead you should be creating a run configuration for an Android app as described in the link I posted.

Comment: Ok, this is kind of emberracing.
I'm kind of a noob. Also my english is retarded.
Can you tell me what to do? (Do it so i can understand it)
Please :)

Comment: Ok, made an AVD (I managed it :D) But then a new problem arrived.
i press run and this shows up:
Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.

The error log shows the following:
NUMBER 1: res\drawable-mdpi\testbackg.png:0: error: Resource entry testbackg is already defined.
NUMBER 2: res\drawable-mdpi\testbackg.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
NUMBER 3: C:\Users\Svein Inge\Android Eclipse\Test 1\res\layout\main.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/testbackg.png').